# Bootstrap navbar text and image horizontal alignement

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I try to create a page with bootstrap 4.
I have a problem with alignment of my navbar. There are an image in each li of my list. All the ul is vertical. i don't understand.  I want to put an horizontal navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-transparent navbar-expand-md text-center pt-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-brand"><img src="[https://stackoverflow.com/logo.png][1]"></div>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  text-center" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="navbar-item active">
                    <img src="[https://stackoverflow.com/maison.png"][1] class="icone ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"></i>Maison</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <img src="[https://stackoverflow.com/equipe.png][1]" class="icone">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Equipe</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <img src="[https://stackoverflow.com/services.png][1]" class="icone">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <img src="[https://stackoverflow.com/client.png][1]" class="icone">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Client</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <img src="[https://stackoverflow.com/contact.png][1]" class="icone">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <img src ="[img/png/newsletter.png][1]" class="icone">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Newsletter</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>  
</nav> 



 .bg-transparent{
     background-color: transparent;
  }
 .icone{
     width: 10%;
     height: auto;
  }
```

Comment: hi Damien, can you provide the relevant CSS for your nav bar? Most likely you have other code for your `UL` and `LI` thats causing some issues.

Comment: thanks crazymatt, well i'll change the system of my code to test an other thing. I don't understand what do you tell about the CSS.